# Eclipse , when typing java code , it will not predict anything , i like it predicting what i am going to type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, predict

I am trying to type `add.setOnClickListener...` and so on. But when I type `add.`, I get nothing. I have gone into pref > Java > editor > content > change the delay time to 0ms, but still nothing. It seems to red line everything instantly, before I have even written the code as well -- as if I don't already know it's not complete yet. I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding but it just does not want to predict for me. I need the prediction as I am still learning the code and it helps jog my memory.

Comment: Try "Ctrl + Space Bar" if that doesn't work then you may not be adding it on the right `Object`.

Comment: @codeMagic looks like fancy formatting doesn't work in comments :-P

Comment: Pressing the Ctrl-space key does not help prediction?

Comment: Cheers for the replys, so i tried ctrl space , but it says it has no default proposals. I did this same thing yesterday but it did seem to predict it correctly for me but now its not doing anything.

Comment: perhaps it is linked to the fact that it is going all error red line red cross on me every time i start a new line ??

Comment: No the red line error should not be the thing causing the error, I get that too. What OS are you on?

Comment: Depending on the errors you have, you may need to fix them first. Also, are you sure you are setting it on the correct `Object`, like a `Button`?

Comment: You're working within a Java Project and Java Source Folder as the UI calls them, right?

Comment: Please look at my recent edit for my answer. Check out my settings and compare them to yours.

Comment: Earlier today I had the same issue. Restarting eclipse fixed it, not sure why.

Comment: All fixed , seemed that when i went into content assist and then advanced , all the boxes had unchecked themselves , all ticked now , and it works , thanks guys

Comment: One tip here.  I often type "this" to get the methods and properties of the current class which don't automatically type assist.  Later I delete the "this" so it looks like I just typed the code in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code-completion setting should be bound to `ctrl + space` but after reading the comments, something must have happened to change that.

You should go to `Windows menu -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content assist` and see your settings there.

[image]

These are the settings I have for comparison.

Comment: All fixed , seemed that when i went into content assist and then advanced , all the boxes had unchecked themselves , all ticked now , and it works , thanks guys